# IE9 Beta resizes form elements onhover bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

The form fields have width applied to them through CSS but when I hover over the textarea it resizes it width-wise to a completely different size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the "cols" attribute is not present.

Wrong:

```
<textarea id="some" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Correct:

```
<textarea id="some"></textarea>
```